# Scale animation on Xamarin.Forms UWP not repeating

Tags: xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm trying to set up an animation on my image similar to *pulse* on https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

So, in Xamarin.Forms, i'm trying to recreate that animation using *ScaleTo* from class ViewExtensions:

```
await image.ScaleTo (1.3, 500);
await image.ScaleTo (1, 500);
await image.ScaleTo (1.3, 500);
await image.ScaleTo (1, 500);
```

But actually nothing appens, my image remains the same.

How can i resolve this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert that [CSS pulse](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/c03507b793165bd62638a265fbef9decfee42413/animate.css#L134) to a custom Parent/Child animation.

#### CSS Pulse:

```
//animation-duration: 1s;
@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

#### Xamarin Animation:

```
new Animation
 {
      { 0, 0.5, new Animation (v => image.Scale = v, 1, 1.05) },
      { 0.5, 1, new Animation (v => image.Scale = v, 1.05, 1) },
 }.Commit(this, "viewAnim", 16, 1000, Easing.Linear);
```